# Formatting JSON data in Python loop

Tags: python, json

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create a JSON payload for an API inside of a loop.

I am able to pull all the information I need from here:

```
response_payload = response.json()
for client in response_payload['user_defined']:
    name = client.get("name")
    value = client.get("value")
    required = client.get("required")
    active = client.get("active")
```

In this loop, I want to add these variables to the following JSON:

```
{
  name: {
    "value": value,
    "required": required,
    "active": active 
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what to add to my loop to get every object. For example:

```
payload = {
  "property_1": {
    "value": "string",
    "required": true,
    "active": true
  },
  "property_2": {
    "value": "string",
    "required": true,
    "active": true
  },
  "property_3": {
    "value": "string",
    "required": true,
    "active": true
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, if I need to re-word anything for better understanding let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Do you generate `property_1`, `property_2` or does that come from somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, this should give you the expected outcome

##### Imports

```py
import json
```

##### Functional code

```py
payload = dict()

for client in response_payload.get('user_defined', []):
    name = client.get("name")
    value = client.get("value")
    required = client.get("required")
    active = client.get("active")
    payload[name] = {'value': value, 'required': required, 'active': active}})

print(json.dumps(payload, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```